# C# Dropdown Reset IE 11 when Debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, localhost, postback

Hey gang I am new here as a poster, but used this site as a great resource when I was in college. I am working on a project for work that when I select the option in the dropdown the page.ispostback should run and keep my selection and allow me to move on. However when I run debug in IE11 and I chose 1 of the 83 options when the postback runs it resets my dropdown to the default option. The bigger issue here is that this is not a problem for everyone who runs debug on the program in IE11. We have confirmed that everything is setup the same in IIS and IE11. I am running a localhost with a windows setup login instead of a anonymous login. Any help/guidance you can provide would greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is any details I am forgetting that could aid you in your assistance.

Comment: Put your dropdownlist binding inside if (!Page.IsPostBack){}

Comment: I am not understanding where to put it, because I did place it in the { } and that did not fix it.

Comment: in page_Load event